# How do we trim text from arbitary start to arbitary end position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, trim

How do I obtain a trimmed down inputted text ?
eg,

var txt = "Hello, how are you???";

To produce result like :

" how are you"

Here, I would like to remove the earlier "Hello," part and remove the later "???" part. I cannot directly use the character positions because it could be any word before comma which user inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove everything up to the comma using a regular exprssion:

```
var txt = "Hello, how are you???";

alert(txt.replace(/^[^,]*,/,''));
```

You can remove any trailing question marks using:

```
var txt = "Hello, how are you???";

alert(txt.replace(/\?*$/,''));
```

and you can combine them using:

```
var txt = "Hello, how are you???";

alert(txt.replace(/(^[^,]*,)|(\?*$)/g,''));
```

Comment: Thanks RobG, this could be useful.

Comment: As an afterthought, would it work for some text such as "Hello, man, how are you????" ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `string.replace` unction.

```
var txt = "Hello, how are you???";
txt = txt.replace('???', '');
txt = txt.replace('Hello,', '');
document.write(txt);
```

Comment: -1 "I cannot directly use the character positions because it could be any word before comma which user inputs."